# CUDA C++ Linking error undefined reference threadIdx.x

Tags: c++, cuda, linker-errors

Hello trying to parallelize a Lattice Boltzmann Solver on CUDA.
Somehow i am getting an error while linking the object files together. The objects compiles without an error.

> LBMSolver.o: In function >`LBMSolver::calcMoments_GPU(LBMUniformGrid2D::LBMGridNode**, int)':
>   tmpxft_00004b33_00000000-3_LBMSolver.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x939): undefined >reference to`blockDim'
>   tmpxft_00004b33_00000000-3_LBMSolver.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x93f): undefined >reference to `blockIdx'
>   tmpxft_00004b33_00000000-3_LBMSolver.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x948): undefined >reference to`threadIdx'
>   tmpxft_00004b33_00000000-3_LBMSolver.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x953): undefined >reference to `blockDim'
>   tmpxft_00004b33_00000000-3_LBMSolver.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x959): undefined >reference to`blockIdx'
>   tmpxft_00004b33_00000000-3_LBMSolver.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x962): undefined >reference to `threadIdx'

Here is my Makefile:

```
OBJS = main.o LBMSolver.o LBMUniformGrid2D.o LBMBoundaryConditions.o   writeVTK.o
CC = g++
NVCC = nvcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -c 
LFLAGS = -Wall
XCOMPILER = -Xcompiler "-Wall"
NVCFLAGS = -c -G -g -ccbin=$(CC) $(XCOMPILER)
NVLFLAGS = -G -g -ccbin=$(CC) $(XCOMPILER)


main : $(OBJS)
    $(NVCC) $(NVLFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o main 

main.o : main.cu LBMSolver.h writeVTK.h
    $(NVCC) $(NVCFLAGS) main.cu

LBMSolver.o : LBMSolver.cu LBMSolver.h LBMUniformGrid2D.h LBMBoundaryConditions.h
    $(NVCC) $(NVCFLAGS) LBMSolver.cu

LBMBoundaryConditions.o : LBMBoundaryConditions.cu LBMBoundaryConditions.h LBMSolver.h
    $(NVCC) $(NVCFLAGS) LBMBoundaryConditions.cu

LBMUniformGrid2D.o : LBMUniformGrid2D.cpp LBMUniformGrid2D.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) LBMUniformGrid2D.cpp

writeVTK.o : writeVTK.h writeVTK.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) writeVTK.cpp

clean_obj: 
    \rm *.o main
```

Function and headerfile that gives the error:

```
#pragma once
#include "LBMUniformGrid2D.h"
#include <cuda.h>

#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define CUDA_HOSTDEV __host__ __device__
#else
#define CUDA_HOSTDEV
#endif

class LBMSolver{
...
CUDA_HOSTDEV void calcMoments_GPU(LBMUniformGrid2D::LBMGridNode **field, int nx);

__host__ __device__ void LBMSolver::calcMoments_GPU(LBMUniformGrid2D::LBMGridNode **field, int nx){
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    LBMUniformGrid2D::LBMGridNode *node;
    node = field[x+y*nx];
    calc_rho_GPU(node);
    calc_ux_GPU(node);
    calc_uy_GPU(node);
    calc_v_GPU(node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define that function containing device code as `__host__`, because device specific features are not supported in host code. Remove that and things will probably compile correctly.

Comment: would probably want to replace the `CUDA_HOSTDEV` macro on the prototype with `__device__` (only) also.

Comment: @RobertCrovella; At least in the code shown, it hasn't been used in a definition, so it is probably safe, but yeah I think that this code need a serious refactor.

Comment: thanks guys. I just did that and it is working now. I also rewrote the macro.